# How to reply to a message with a file using discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

I try to make a bot that when you type '!roll' it selects a random videos in an array and respond to the message with it.

The JS part works but the files is not send.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ],
});

const prefix = '!';
const jets = [
    "assets/01.mp4",
    "assets/02.mp4",
    "ETC..."
]

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Prêt à lancer les dés !");
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    console.log(message.author.username + " a utilisé : " + prefix+command);
    if(command  === "roll") {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * jets.length);
        message.reply("Dés lancés :", {files: [jets[random]]});
    }
    else if(command === "help") {
        message.reply("Utilise " + prefix + "roll pour lancer les dés.");
    }
});
```

What I expected is this type of response from the bot to anyone who type '!roll' :[image: What I expect from the bot]

If you have any idea, it might be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a `string` as a file. `files` only accepts an **array** of [Attachment](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Attachment)s

```js
message.reply({ 
    content: "Dés lancés :", 
    files: [{ 
        name: 'file.mp4', 
        attachment: jets[random] // path or buffer
    }] 
});
```